# Spring Jpa Repository crash on insert

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to implement a repository for refresh JWT tokens and I can't save my token in postgresql.

My entity :

```
@Entity(name = "refreshtoken")
public class RefreshToken {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private long id;

  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String user;

  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String token;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Instant expiryDate;

  public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

  public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

  public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

  public Instant getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public void setExpiryDate(Instant expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
```

The refresh token is initialised with the right values.
The logs are

> Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence') Hibernate: insert
> into refreshtoken (expiry_date, token, user, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
> 2022-04-08 11:17:22.475 ERROR 24272 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe
> sur ou prΦs de ½ user ╗   Positioná: 47 2022-04-08 11:17:22.483 DEBUG
> 24272 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        :
> Failed to complete request:
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
> statement 2022-04-08 11:17:22.497 ERROR 24272 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/xatis-web] threw
> exception  [Request processing failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
> not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute
> statement] with root cause
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou
> prΦs de ½ user ╗   Positioná: 47

I have spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
I created refreshtoken table manualy but I also noticed that after it crashed, all field are created except user.

Any help would be welcome, thanks

Comment: 1. Instant may not be supported by your hibernate version
2. 'user' may be a key word for postgresql, i can't tell for sure.

Comment: user was indeed a reserved word, thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Like Manuel pointed out in the comment, user is a reserved word in postgresql

Answer (score 0):

"user" is a reserved keyword for Postgresql